# How to sync video from my phone to any cloud service?

Tags: sync, video, backup

I have Microsoft Lumia and it sync photos automatically to onedrive, but it is not doing the same with videos.
I want to keep my videos in sync with any cloud service, is that possible and which cloud service and app can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your phone can also upload videos to OneDrive, but it needs WiFi, you cannot do it over a mobile connection.

To enable video upload to OneDrive (if it's not already enabled), do the following:

1. Open the Photos app
2. Tap the "..." icon to open the app bar and tap on "settings"
3. Scroll down to "Auto upload" and tap on OneDrive
4. Under Videos, select the "Best quality" option

Other apps may also support auto-uploading videos, though I can't name any specific ones since I only use OneDrive myself. If you want to see which apps might be supported, do steps 1 and 2 above, then in step 3 tap on "apps" and then "get apps". You'll see apps for a number of services, including popular ones like DropBox, Flickr and Picasa.

For more information, see [this how-to at WindowsPhone.com](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/how-to/wp8/photos/automatically-save-the-photos-and-videos-i-take-to-onedrive).